# Is there a way to plot a 3d figure in matplotlib in given case

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I am trying to plot two figures in matplotlib
one of a tapering square pipe
one of an uniform square pipe

I am importing the X Y values from excel and making 3lists containing the X Y Z co-ordinates for each square cross-section of the pipe.

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel(r'H:\Hrishikesh1\lidar_excel_data.xlsx')

#list of x co-ordinates of the 1st(bottom-most square cross-section)
x1 = list(df["X_square"])
#list of y co-ordinates of the 1st(bottom-most square cross-section)
y1 = list(df["Y_square"])
#list of z co-ordinates 
z1 = np.linspace(0, 10, num=22)

#lists for storing all the co-ordinates for tapering pipe 
x_sqt=[]
y_sqt=[]
z_sqt=[]

#lists for storing all the co-ordinates for straight pipe
x_sqs=[]
y_sqs=[]
z_sqs=[]

#using the X Y co-ordinates of 1st Square new X Y Z co-ordinates are plotted for each Square 
#crosssection (Tapering)
for i in z1 :
    for j in x1 :
        x_sqt.append((((1.5*10-i))/(1.5*10))*j)
        z_sqt.append(i)
    for k in y1 :
        y_sqt.append((((1.5*10-i))/(1.5*10))*k)

#using the X Y co-ordinates of 1st Square new X Y Z co-ordinates are plotted for each Square 
#crosssection (straight/uniform pipe)
for i in z1 :
    for j in x1 :
        x_sqs.append(j)
        z_sqs.append(i)
    for k in y1 :
        y_sqs.append(k)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
 
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d') 

x1 = x_sqt 
y1 = y_sqt 
z1 = z_sqt

# plotting
ax.plot3D(x1, y1, z1, 'red')
ax.set_title('Plot Taper')


ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')

x2 = x_sqs 
y2 = y_sqs 
z2 = z_sqs

ax.plot3D(x2, y2, z2, 'green')
ax.set_title('Plot Straight')
plt.show()
```

As you see in the code I have generated X Y Z co-ordinates for each square cross-section and mapped them on increasing Z values.

Now this figure is in the form of individually stacked squares which are connected at starting point as we move from one square to another.

**MAIN QUESTION - Is there any any way to use these co-ordinates to generate a 3d looking plot, as in, instead of being individual lines can the sides of the pipes be in surface form ?**

Images of plot attached below

[Plot of pipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azwCY.png)

[Top view of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdGbi.png)

[Line connecting the starting X Y values in each square cross-section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YZnf.png)